# WSO2 5.6.0 Migration process was stopped - OIDCScopeDataMigrator

Tags: wso2, migration, upgrade, wso2-identity-server

When migrating WSO2 Identity Server from 5.5.0 to 5.6.0, I'm getting the following error:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:31,009]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -  Migration Versions List......................... 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:31,009]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -  5.0.0 to 5.0.0-SP1 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:31,009]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -  5.0.0-SP1 to 5.1.0 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:31,009]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -  5.1.0 to 5.2.0 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:31,009]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -  5.2.0 to 5.3.0 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:31,009]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -  5.3.0 to 5.4.0 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:31,009]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -  5.4.0 to 5.5.0 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:31,009]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -  5.5.0 to 5.6.0 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:31,009]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -  5.6.0 to 5.7.0 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:31,010]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Start Version : 5.0.0 to 5.0.0-SP1 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:31,010]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Start Version : 5.0.0-SP1 to 5.1.0 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:31,010]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Start Version : 5.1.0 to 5.2.0 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:31,010]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Start Version : 5.2.0 to 5.3.0 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:31,010]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Start Version : 5.3.0 to 5.4.0 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:31,010]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Start Version : 5.4.0 to 5.5.0 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:31,010]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Start Version : 5.5.0 to 5.6.0 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:31,015]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.VersionMigration} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Version : 5.6.0, Migration Step : SchemaMigrator starting...........................  
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:31,016]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.SchemaMigrator} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Executing Identity Migration Scripts. 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:31,017]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.DataSourceManager} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Initialized the identity database successfully. 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:32,253] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.SchemaMigrator} -  Error occurred while executing SQL script for migrating database 
java.lang.Exception: Error occurred while executing :   CREATE INDEX IDX_AT_TI_UD ON IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN(AUTHZ_USER, TENANT_ID, TOKEN_STATE, USER_DOMAIN)
    at org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.SchemaMigrator.executeSQL(SchemaMigrator.java:231)
  ...
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Invalid default value for 'TIME_CREATED'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  ...
    at org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.SchemaMigrator.executeSQL(SchemaMigrator.java:201)
    ... 65 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:32,255] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.SchemaMigrator} -  Error occurred while executing SQL script for migrating database 
java.lang.Exception: Error occurred while executing SQL script for migrating database
    at org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.SchemaMigrator.executeSQLScript(SchemaMigrator.java:172)
  ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Error occurred while executing :   CREATE INDEX IDX_AT_TI_UD ON IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN(AUTHZ_USER, TENANT_ID, TOKEN_STATE, USER_DOMAIN)
    at org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.SchemaMigrator.executeSQL(SchemaMigrator.java:231)
    at org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.SchemaMigrator.executeSQLScript(SchemaMigrator.java:162)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Invalid default value for 'TIME_CREATED'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  ...
    at org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.SchemaMigrator.executeSQL(SchemaMigrator.java:201)
    ... 65 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:32,257]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.VersionMigration} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Version : 5.6.0, Migration Step : SpClaimDialectSchemaMigrator starting...........................  
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:32,259]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.v560.migrator.SpClaimDialectSchemaMigrator} -  SP_CLAIM_DIALECT does not exist in the database. Hence adding the table. 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:32,259]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.SchemaMigrator} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Executing Identity Migration Scripts. 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:32,960]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.SchemaMigrator} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Identity DB Migration script executed successfully. 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:32,960]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.VersionMigration} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Version : 5.6.0, Migration Step : ClaimDataMigrator starting...........................  
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:34,584] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.v560.migrator.ClaimDataMigrator} -  Error while migrating claim data for tenant: ten.com 
org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.exception.ClaimMetadataException: Invalid Claim URI : http://wso2.org/claims/phoneNumbers for Claim Dialect : http://wso2.org/claims
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.dao.ClaimDAO.getClaimId(ClaimDAO.java:170)
  ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:42,405]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.VersionMigration} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Version : 5.6.0, Migration Step : SessionDataMigrator starting...........................  
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:42,424]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Start Version : 5.6.0 to 5.7.0 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:42,449]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.config.OAuthServerConfiguration} -  'RequestObjectBuilder' element for Type: request_param_value_builderis not configured in identity.xml. Therefore instantiating default request object builder: org.wso2.carbon.identity.openidconnect.RequestParamRequestObjectBuilder 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:42,451]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.VersionMigration} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Version : 5.7.0, Migration Step : SchemaMigrator starting...........................  
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:42,451]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.SchemaMigrator} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Executing Identity Migration Scripts. 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:44,601]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.SchemaMigrator} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Identity DB Migration script executed successfully. 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:44,601]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.VersionMigration} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Version : 5.7.0, Migration Step : SchemaMigrator starting...........................  
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:44,601]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.SchemaMigrator} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Executing Identity Migration Scripts. 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:46,415]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.SchemaMigrator} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Identity DB Migration script executed successfully. 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:46,415]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.VersionMigration} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Version : 5.7.0, Migration Step : SchemaMigrator starting...........................  
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:46,415]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.SchemaMigrator} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Executing Identity Migration Scripts. 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:47,732]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.SchemaMigrator} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Identity DB Migration script executed successfully. 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:47,732]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.VersionMigration} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Version : 5.7.0, Migration Step : OAuthDataMigrator starting...........................  
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:42:47,732]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.v570.migrator.OAuthDataMigrator} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Migration starting on OAuth2 access token table. 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:43:18,193]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.v570.migrator.OAuthDataMigrator} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Migration starting on Authorization code table 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:43:18,240]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.VersionMigration} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Version : 5.7.0, Migration Step : OIDCScopeDataMigrator starting...........................  
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:43:18,240]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.v570.migrator.OIDCScopeDataMigrator} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Started to migrate OIDC scopes 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:43:18,480] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -  Migration process was stopped. 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth/dto/ScopeDTO
    at org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.v570.migrator.OIDCScopeDataMigrator.getScopeDTOs(OIDCScopeDataMigrator.java:120)
    at org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.v570.migrator.OIDCScopeDataMigrator.addScopes(OIDCScopeDataMigrator.java:105)
    at org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.v570.migrator.OIDCScopeDataMigrator.migrateOIDCScopes(OIDCScopeDataMigrator.java:78)
    at org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.v570.migrator.OIDCScopeDataMigrator.migrate(OIDCScopeDataMigrator.java:69)
    at org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.VersionMigration.migrate(VersionMigration.java:41)
    at org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl.execute(MigrationClientImpl.java:83)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.internal.IdentityCoreServiceComponent.activate(IdentityCoreServiceComponent.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:515)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:220)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1066)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5370)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5668)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1690)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.dto.ScopeDTO cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.is.migration_5.7.0
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 67 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:43:18,481]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -  ............................................................................................ 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:43:18,481]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -  ............................................................................................ 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:43:18,481]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -  ............................................................................................ 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:43:18,482]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -  ............................................................................................ 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:43:18,482]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -  ............................................................................................ 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:43:18,482]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -  ............................................................................................ 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:43:18,482]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -  ............................................................................................ 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:43:18,482]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -  ............................................................................................ 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:43:18,482]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -  ............................................................................................ 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-12 18:43:18,621] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.email.mgt.internal.I18nMgtServiceComponent} -  Error while activating I18n Management bundle 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid template type name provided : null
    at org.wso2.carbon.email.mgt.util.I18nEmailUtil.getNormalizedName(I18nEmailUtil.java:73)
    at org.wso2.carbon.email.mgt.EmailTemplateManagerImpl.addDefaultEmailTemplates(EmailTemplateManagerImpl.java:280)
    at org.wso2.carbon.email.mgt.internal.I18nMgtServiceComponent.loadDefaultEmailTemplates(I18nMgtServiceComponent.java:96)
    at org.wso2.carbon.email.mgt.internal.I18nMgtServiceComponent.activate(I18nMgtServiceComponent.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.internal.IdentityCoreServiceComponent.activate(IdentityCoreServiceComponent.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:515)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:220)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1066)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5370)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5668)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1690)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I assume this is the migrator file [OIDCScopeDataMigrator](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/blob/master/modules/migration/migration-service/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/is/migration/service/v570/migrator/OIDCScopeDataMigrator.java).

I tracked the jar file to repository/components/features/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth_6.0.14.jar and it doesn't have the class ScopeDTO. But changing that particular jar file will affect the migration.

Did anyone come across this? What can be a suitable way to resolve this? Any help is appreciated.

**EDITED**

After reconfiguring from the start in a new folder, this error doesn't show up and only one change was made, I enabled SCIM2  event listener and disabled SCIM  event listener, now I've done the opposite. How would this config change the migrator jar?

Answer (score 0):

The log has this line

```
[2019-03-13 18:09:44,826]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.v570.migrator.OIDCScopeDataMigrator} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Started to migrate OIDC scopes
```

So I hope it is executing the migration for 5.6.0 to 5.7.0. That is the reason it can't find the ScopeDTO class.

As your requirement is to migrate from  5.5.0 to 5.6.0. You need to specify migration-config.yaml file found in the /migration-resources folder. Pls refer this [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release) for more info

```
migrationEnable: "true"

currentVersion: "5.5.0"

migrateVersion: "5.6.0
```

Comment: in the above doc, the **migration resources** is version 5.x.x and it mentions copying the `org.wso2.carbon.is.migration-5.7.0.jar` from migration resources to be placed inside `/repository/components/dropins`. Where to find the migration resources for 5.6.0?

Comment: The migration resources for 5.7.0 will also have the resources for the 5.6.0 migration(migration resources for 5.7.0  will include all the migration resource from 5.1.0 to 5.7.0). You need to change to the configuration in migration-config.yaml file as per your current and migrate version

Comment: I have the same `currentVersion: "5.5.0", migrateVersion: "5.6.0` in the migration-config.yaml file.

Comment: I have added some more of the logs from the beginning of the migration to where it throws the error. Please also see the edited text.

Comment: You can clearly see in the logs `INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -   WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Start Version : 5.6.0 to 5.7.0 `, the migration client tries to run 5.7.0. So the issue must be with the migrateVersion. Do you have "5.6.0"